# On the eigenvalue problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

A standard approach to the eigenvalue problem is as follows. We are looking for solutions $\omega$ of the following:

$\Omega\vec v=\omega\vec v \tag{1},$

where $\vec v$ is some element of our vector space. We conclude that if there exists a solution, it must then satisfy

$$(\Omega-\omega\hat 1)\vec v=\vec 0, \tag{2}$$

in which $\hat 1$ is the identity operator. Next, we see that if such a solution exists, then the operator $(\Omega-\omega\hat 1)$ must not be invertible, a statement which is equivalent to $\det(\Omega-\omega\hat 1)=0$. This has the form:

$$\sum_{n=0}^N c_n\omega^n \tag{3}.$$

Finally, we conclude that the eigenvalues of $\Omega$ must be the solutions of the above "characteristic equation" when it is equal to zero.

My problem is this, we know that *if* a solution of $(2)$ exists, the operator in brackets must be singular, however we seem to rely on the converse: if $(\Omega-\omega\hat 1)$ is singular (i.e. $\omega$ solves $\det (\Omega-\omega\hat 1)=0$), then $\omega$ is a solution of $(1)$, when determining the eigenvalues. I don't see why this must be true.

Comment: Assuming we are in the finite-dimensional case, there exists a solution $v\ne0$ such that (2) holds if and only if $\Omega-\omega\hat 1$ is singular. The latter holds if and only if the determinant of $\Omega-\omega\hat 1$ is zero. So, finding those $\omega$'s (the eigenvalues) first will allow us to find the $v$'s (the eigenvectors).

Comment: @KBS I can see that if a solution exists it implies the operator is singular, I do not see why the converse must be true.

Comment: Please be precise. What solution exactly? You mean $v$? Note that $v$ must be nonzero.

Comment: Sorry yes, I mean $v$; I'm unsure why $\Omega-\omega\hat 1$ being singular implies there exists a non-zero solution, $\vec v$, of $(1)$.

Comment: This is any book on linear algebra. You can try to prove it yourself too.

Comment: Ah, I am coming at this from the angle of learning quantum mechanics in physics, I'm not covering a linear algebra book. Is there any chance this has name or there is a keyword I could use to find the proof?

Comment: A linear map $f: V\rightarrow W$ is one to one iff $\operatorname{ker}(f)=\{0\}$. Thus if $f$ is not one to one, there must be $v\neq 0$ with $f(v)=0$.

Comment: If you are doing quantum mechanics you will need to learn linear algebra and even more.  You can check this book https://linear.axler.net/ or any other book on linear algebra.

Comment: I am already fairly familiar with QM, I appreciate this is a basic topic but I am re-visiting this after some time and had never thought about this. @Hirshy thank you for your comment, if you want to write this as an answer I'll accept it since it answers my question. Thanks guys :)